# What's a good transform for decaying function with a plateau

Tags: multiple-regression, curve-fitting

I have a dataset (y vs. t) that I think is best described by:

- Slight initial downward slope
- At maybe t = 1 or 2, steep downward slope
- Asymptote at y = 0

[image]
[image: Actual, fuzzy data]

I would like to transform the data so I can build a strong linear regression.

The second portion looks good for exponential decay (use ln(y) as the dependent variable), but how do I combine with the first part?

**How should I transform my data before regression?**

**Images below are intended to respond to commenters' requests**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: if your data shows a clear pattern, presumably you want a model that fits that shape. Why are you trying to transform first? What is the transformation to achieve?

Comment: The data is too fuzzy to see clearly with the naked eye. I'd like to use p-values to confirm/refute my intuition. I'm trying to build a transform before I regress that will show good significance (and later work for predictions).

Comment: Agree with @Glen_b. Might be worth taking a look at polynomial distributed lag models. Difficult to tell from the graph if these would be helpful, though.

Comment: Your approach appears to be misguided - you're transforming in order to make a regression 'significant' - and you will almost certainly succeed, but the significance will be meaningless. Perhaps you'd be better served by a nonparametric regression approach, perhaps a local polynomial in the logs, or a logspline fit. "I want to confirm my intuition" relates to your preferred outcome, not what the actual point of the activity is. What is $y$ measuring?

Comment: To start with, from the look of that data, take logs of both $y$ and $t$ so you can perhaps begin to make out what's going on.

Comment: I won't try guessing a suitable model form from a plot of the raw data. Assuming that all your y values are positive, a plot with a log scale for y seems the second move.

Comment: I believe there's exponential decay, plus the plateau (from domain knowledge, not stats).  ln(y) vs. t (pure exponential decay) gives a model with p-level = 0.00093 (there are many binary variables which improve the model, but they're a distraction here), but I also want to catch the plateau. Please forgive my lack of good statistical vocabulary - I'm more of an engineer.

Comment: With 30,000 data points a very low P-value is not surprising even for a lousy model.

Comment: Glen - Y is roughly, "how much does someone like a web page?". I expect the data to be pretty flat when extremely fast, but exponential decay past this point (maybe after a second).

Comment: What values can $y$ take? Can it be 0? The ln(y) vs ln(time) plot ... what value is the line of points at the bottom? It looks like maybe you should model the probability of being down there, and the way the mean changes when it isn't there.

Comment: y can be 0+, but I limited to 0.00001 so I could transform. The largest value in this set is 750.

Comment: Glen - Many thanks.  Splitting the model into logit*mean has made the data appear much stronger.  So glad you commented.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the overall mean is not the same as the mean conditional on not being zero; if you do need the overall mean, you should be able to compute it.

Comment: workglide - should I post my comments as an answer? It might help if the question was also modified to more clearly reflect what you needed to know.

Comment: How do you obtain Y? Is this an objective measure? Is this a survey answer?

Answer (score 1):

A Gaussian Mixture ([1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution.fit.html),[2](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fleet/courses/2503/fall11/Handouts/mixtureModel.pdf),[3](http://www.autonlab.org/tutorials/gmm.html)) might be an acceptable, "textbook", fit for your first plot.

The second plot looks like hyperbolic transformed material.  When I see the second plot I think $ y=\frac {1}{x}$.   Could you try transforming the second using $ y_{2} = \frac{1}{y}$ and show what that graph looks like?

Glens has a good point: If you are trying to do the speaking for the data, you can always accomplish that goal, you can always "win", but it most often causes you to lose.  Be careful to let the data do the talking.

One question behind the question is: what is your motivation.  The human brain is an amazing computer able to find signal when the signal-to-noise ratio is stunningly bad.  We see patterns where they are highly obscured.  The human heart is deceitful above all things - our emotions can mislead us ten thousand times a day.  We see patterns that aren't there and we write them into the data and thereby guarantee that our "solution" doesn't actually work.  Being able to tell the difference between a highly obscured pattern and a pattern that isn't there takes mental clarity of vision into the emotional state.  Hard stuff.  Sorry for the philosophy lesson.

Comment: I appreciate the philosophy and agree. I'm applying domain knowledge, not pattern recognition (looks like a cloud to me). Hoping there's a usable transform to find my answer (your links might be over my head, but will try).

Comment: The motivation: a strong model will help the customer. The plateau is a useful result in itself.

Comment: Added inverse of t per your request (y inverse is too distributed to see anything at all)

Comment: wrong inverse.  Not inverse of "T", inverse of what the y-axis is.

Comment: I tried inverse of y first, but it's impossible to read (most values are around 1 or 10^6).

Comment: Can you supply a 4-plot of the y-data?  http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/4plot.htm